# Not able to finding Mobile user checkbox in user detail page? version summer 20 release

Tags: apex, community, salesforce1-app, administration, mobile

If Salesforce removed in summer 20 version.. Any alternate way for "Mobile user" checkbox feature that exactly provided. i.e (mobile experience to the user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&mode=1&id=000349471 , starting Summer'20 Mobile Web Experience would be retired. The alternative that salesforce suggests is to use Salesforce Mobile App.

> Starting in June, 2020, you need to have the Salesforce mobile app installed on your device or use Lightning Experience on iPad Browsers.

Comment: Hi @swetha thanks, great answer